# jQuery extra Ghost divs? Need to wipe function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have a few columns, and I have a tool to add data to each column (will be linking it up to a DB in the future) and remove data. All using jQuery to make it happen from form input fields.

However if I add a few two items to a column, it adds an extra one below, than an extra 2 below, and than an extra 3 below.

Maybe my brain is mush from working on this for the last little bit, but any help would be appreciated. Full working example at JSFiddle below. I will be grateful.

http://jsfiddle.net/4VcAY/

The full function is at jsfiddle but here is the add div:

```
$('#' + identifier + 's').append('<div class="panel panel-default" id="' + inputId + '"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">' + inputName + '</h3></div><div class="panel-body">' + inputDescription + '</div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

How you're adding the onClick inside of formController() is causing it to fire multiple times.

Add "alert(event.target.id);" after your "i++" and pass event into the function. Then add more then 1 of the same item type and you'll see the onClick fire too many times and with invalid values.

Comment: Thanks for this. It is helpful. Do you have a suggestion how I should resolve?

Comment: [EDIT] Nevermind, figured it out by using .off before the .on event thus preventing multiple fires. Credit goes to you on this one!